# Find the coordinates of each point in an InkCanvas

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, inkcanvas

In my UWP app I'm trying to obtain the coordinates of each point that is part of an ink stroke in an InkCanvas, but the official documentation doesn't seem to talk about it, do anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing but from the documentation it looks like:

```
foreach (Stroke s in yourInkCanvas.Strokes)
{
    foreach (StylusPoint sp in s.StylusPoints)
    {
        double X = sp.X;
        double Y = sp.Y;
    }
}
```